# Use contents of 1 form to set focus on a field in another form

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that needs the contents of multiple fields manipulated. I have written the code to do the manipulation but want it to be performed on many fields. I have set up another table that contains the name of the fields that need to be changed and then want to use it to set the field name that needs to be inspected next.
I have tried

```
Dim FieldName  As Control 
Dim FieldName1  As String
DoCmd.OpenForm "FieldsForm", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
DoCmd.GoToRecord , Fields, acFirst
FieldName1 = Forms!FieldsForm.Field
FieldName = FieldName1
```

it comes up with error
Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 0):

Not clear enough what should be done with data in fields, here is an example - you read target field name from another form, then using this name you access the field on current form, set the focus tho this field and change the value:

```
Dim FieldControl  As Control
Dim FieldName  As String

DoCmd.OpenForm "FieldsForm"
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst

'read target field name from textbox with name "FieldReference"
FieldName = Forms!FieldsForm.FieldReference.Value

'get the control by name
Set FieldControl = Me.Controls(FieldName)

'Now you can operate with target control
FieldControl.SetFocus
FieldControl.Value = "some data"
```